# How to make a program to print the series : 1,12,123...12345678910,1234567891011...& so on to the nth term?

Tags: java

```
//I tried this one but output was wrong for tenth term
 import java.io.*;
 public class series
 {
     public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
     {
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         int n,i,i1=0,s=0,c=0;
         System.out.println("Enter the term of the series you want to get");
         n=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
         for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
         {
             i1=i;
             while (i1!=0)
             {
                 c+=1;
                 i1=i1/10;
             }
             s=(int)(s*(Math.pow(10,c))+i);
             c=0;
             System.out.print(s+" ");
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks! ( was wrong isnt a good problem description, rather give the expected and the actual value )

Comment: Beyond that: you want others to spend their Sunday free time to help you with your question. Then it would be really helpful if you would be willing to spend your time to indent your code correctly. Many people will see that sorry code dump of yours and do only thing: downvote and move on.

Comment: @GhostCat Too late :-(

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Why? Chances are that this OP might write up another question at some point.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why you are using your current approach.  I would go about this by keeping track of the previous term which was printed.

```
StringBuilder term = new StringBuilder("");
final int N = 20;

for (int i=1; i <= N; ++i) {
    term.append(i);
    if (i > 1) System.out.print(",");
    System.out.print(term.toString());
}
```

### Demo

Edit: The reason I suggest using a string to display each term is that your requirement appears to mainly be one of *presentation*.  That is, you're not actually doing any math with each term, so why not just avoid a numeric type completely, which also avoids things like overflow and potential loss of precision.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52024052/3788176) is neat, I think that the exercise is sufficiently basic that `StringBuilder` is beyond its scope (*).

Instead, you can use a nested for loop:

```
final int N = 20;

for (int i=1; i <= N; ++i) {
    if (i > 1) System.out.print(",");
    for (int a = 1; a <= i; ++a) {
        System.out.print(a);
    }
}
```

(This is also going to be more memory efficient, since there is no need to keep reallocating the `StringBuffer`'s internal buffer as `i` increases. But this is really of secondary (or even lesser) concern).

(*) Yes, you could do the same without StringBuilder, just using String concatenation; but that would be inefficient in ways that beginners may not "get", and so it is something that is best just steered around. Nested loops are far more generally useful than string concatenation in whatever form as a concept to get your head around.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you are getting wrong output after 10th term is Integer Overflow. You can use long to get rid of that to certain more terms but a definitely better solution is as answered using Strings